# Fórmula de Haversine para SQL SERVER

Tags: java, android, sql-server, web-service, google-maps

Galera, eu tenho um app em Android que usa API Google Maps. No mapa, eu recebo dados de um banco de dados SQL Server. Eu preciso criar um raio em KM em que eu só carregue os dados do banco que estão dentro deste raio. Isso baseado na geolocalização atual do dispositivo do usuário.

Eu utilizava o MySQL, nele eu conseguia fazer isso usando esta fórmula:

```
SELECT DISTINCT filiais.icon_logo_maps,
                filiais.latitude_fil,
                filiais.longitude_fil,
                filiais.nr_cnpj_filial,
                (6371 acos(cos(radians(latitude_dispositivo))cos(radians(filiais.latitude_fil))cos(radians(longitude_dispositivo) - radians(filiais.longitude_fil))sin(radians(latitude_dispositivo))sin(radians(filiais.latitude_fil)) AS distance
  FROM _using.produto
       INNER JOIN _using.filiais ON _using.produto.cnpj_filial = _using.filiais.nr_cnpj_filial
 WHERE _using.produto.subcat = 'mercad'
HAVING distance <= 7;
```

Como eu poderia usar esta mesma fórmula para o SQL Server?

No SQL SERVER eu encontro o seguinte erro:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Nome de coluna
>   'distance' inválido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para `SQL Server 2008` ou superior existe o tipo `GEOGRAPHY` que "traduz" a latitude e longitude em uma localização. Feito isso você pode calculá-la antes de utilizar para a sua validação.

```
WITH relacao AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT f.icon_logo_maps,
                  f.latitude_fil,
                  f.longitude_fil,
                  f.nr_cnpj_filial,
                  CAST('POINT(' + p.latitude_dispositivo + ' ' + p.longitude_dispositivo + ')' AS GEOGRAPHY).STDistance(
                  CAST('POINT(' + f.latitude_fil + ' ' + f.longitude_fil + ')' AS GEOGRAPHY)) AS distance
    FROM _using.produto p
         INNER JOIN _using.filiais f ON p.cnpj_filial = f.nr_cnpj_filial
   WHERE p.subcat = 'mercad'
)
SELECT r.icon_logo_maps,
       r.latitude_fil,
       r.longitude_fil,
       r.nr_cnpj_filial
  FROM relacao r
 WHERE r.distance <= 7;
```

> [**`POINT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb933811(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> ***Aplica-se a:** SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 até a versão atual), Banco de dados SQL do Windows Azure (versão inicial até a versão atual).*
>
> Constrói uma instância de `GEOGRAPHY` que representa uma instância de `Point` de seus valores de latitude e de longitude e um SRID (ID de referência espacial).